# 5 qubit quantum error correction property

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

Having 
$$\eqalign{
|v_0⟩&=|00000⟩+|11000⟩+|01100⟩+|00110⟩+ {}\cr
     &\quad |00011⟩+|10001⟩−|10010⟩-|10100⟩− {}\cr
     &\quad |01001⟩−|01010⟩−|00101⟩−|11110⟩− {}\cr
     &\quad |11101⟩-|11011⟩−|10100⟩−|01111⟩.\cr}$$
A expanded 5 qubit quantum state for QECC

There is a corresponding orthogonal state $|v_1⟩$, obtained by switching the 0's and the 1's in $|v_0⟩$. Together they span a two dimensional code subspace, consisting of the states

$$|\psi⟩ = z_0|v_0⟩ + z_1|v_1⟩.$$

You can now check that if we take the partial trace over any three out of the
five factors, there holds

$${\rm Tr}_{123}|v_0⟩⟨v_0| = {\rm Tr}{123}|v_1⟩⟨v_1| = 1$$
$${\rm Tr}_{123}|v_0⟩⟨v_1| = {\rm Tr}_{123}|v_1⟩⟨v_0| = 0.$$

How do I prove this property?